# What is the best way to deal with image sizes in object detection using YOLO v. 4?

Tags: preprocessing, yolo

I am using [YOLO v. 4](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) to perform object detection and classification on a large number of images. I do this through the Python interface. My images are all sorts of sizes and aspect ratios.
Examples of using Darknet / YOLO from the command line such as in [this Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12QusaaRj_lUwCGDvQNfICpa7kA7_a2dE#scrollTo=zROXpfwcMcJW) simply throw images at the `darknet` executable without any apparent considaration for image size or aspect ratio. This makes me think YOLO does some scaling/cropping/insertion of blank parts automatically.
Then when I look at [the `darknet_images` Python module](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/darknet_images.py) that comes with the Darknet/YOLO framework, the approach seems to be [to use `cv2` to scale images](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/103d301ccbc19e47e002005bdfdbaf07a92cd880/darknet_images.py#L109) to the size of the network prior to detection in YOLO. In particular, this seems to generally skew the aspect ratio. Now I am confused: should I scale or not prior to detection via `darknet.detect_image()`?
I *can* create image objects with `darknet.make_image()` using the image's native size and feed them to `darknet.detect_image()` without any complaints, so what does Darknet do about the size in that case?
I am also wondering if it would be better to scale a, say 1000x500 image to my Darknet network's size of 608x608 as a 608x304 image in a 608x608 "frame", leaving the remainder of the frame blank (white or black)? Or should I flat out scale the 1000x500 image to 608x608, distorting the aspect ratio heavily? I suppose YOLO's training takes some amount of distortion into account via data augmentation, but I guess there must be limits to how much distortion it can tolerate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have figured it out now. When using [`darknet.detect_image`](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/103d301ccbc19e47e002005bdfdbaf07a92cd880/darknet.py#L164), it calls [`predict_image`](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/103d301ccbc19e47e002005bdfdbaf07a92cd880/darknet.py#L307) which in turn is [`network_predict_image`](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/103d301ccbc19e47e002005bdfdbaf07a92cd880/src/network.c#L1040). The latter [resizes the image](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/103d301ccbc19e47e002005bdfdbaf07a92cd880/src/network.c#L1051) if it is not already the same size as the network's input layer.

If you instead call `darknet detector test` from the command line, as I have seen examples do as mentioned in my original question, the "chain of command" goes through [`test_detector`](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/103d301ccbc19e47e002005bdfdbaf07a92cd880/src/detector.c#L1603) which [resizes the image](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/103d301ccbc19e47e002005bdfdbaf07a92cd880/src/detector.c#L1659) if it is not already the size of the network's input layer.

So, in any case it seems that images get resized to fit the network's input layer along the way and I do not have to do anything in particular to handle it.